# get entities all latest records in u-sql script

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake, u-sql

how to fetch all employees latest records in U-SQL

```
@employees = 
    SELECT * FROM 
        ( VALUES
        (1, "Noah",   100, (int?)10000, new DateTime(2012,05,31), "cell:030-0074321,office:030-0076545"),
 (1, "Noah",   100, (int?)10000, new DateTime(2012,06,30), "cell:030-0074321,office:030-0076545"),
        (2, "Sophia", 100, (int?)15000, new DateTime(2012,03,19), "cell:(5) 555-4729,office:(5) 555-3745"),
        (3, "Liam",   100, (int?)30000, new DateTime(2014,09,14), "cell:(5) 555-3932"),
        (4, "Amy",    100, (int?)35000, new DateTime(1999,02,27), "cell:(171) 555-7788,office:(171) 555-6750, home:(425) 555-6238"),

        (5, "amy", 100, (int?)15000, new DateTime(2015,01,12), "cell:0921-12 34 65,office:0921-12 34 67"),
        (6, "Emma",   200, (int?)8000,  new DateTime(2014,03,08), (string)null),
        (7, "Jacob",  200, (int?)8000,  new DateTime(2014,09,02), ""),
        (8, "Olivia", 200, (int?)8000,  new DateTime(2013,12,11), "cell:88.60.15.31,office:88.60.15.32"),
        (9, "Mason",  300, (int?)50000, new DateTime(2016,01,01), "cell:(91) 555 22 82,office:(91) 555 91 99, home:(425) 555-2819"),
        (10, "Ava",   400, (int?)15000, new DateTime(2014,09,14), "cell:91.24.45.40,office:91.24.45.41"),
        (11, "Ethan", 400, (int?)9000,  new DateTime(2015,08,22), "cell:(604) 555-4729,office:(604) 555-3745"),
        (12, "David", 800, (int?)100,   new DateTime(2016,11,01), "cell:(171) 555-1212"),
        (13, "Andrew", 100, (int?)null, new DateTime(1995,07,16), "cell:(1) 135-5555,office:(1) 135-4892"),
        (14, "Jennie", 100, (int?)34000, new DateTime(2000,02,12), "cell:(5) 555-3392,office:(5) 555-7293")
        ) AS T(EmpID, EmpName, DeptID, Salary, StartDate, PhoneNumbers);

@result =
    SELECT *
    FROM @employees
    ORDER BY EmpID DESC
    ;    

OUTPUT @result
TO "sample.txt"
USING Outputters.Csv();
```

Comment: What is the expected output based on the data above?

Comment: Hello @steve - consider editing the question and provide more context  and what you are exactly trying to achieve. You will get more relevant and helpful answers then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use one of the analytic functions like `ROW_NUMBER` or `RANK`, partition by `EmpId` and order by `Start Date` but *descending*, something like this:

```
@result =
    SELECT *
    FROM
    (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY EmpID ORDER BY StartDate DESC ) AS rn
    FROM @employees
    ) AS x
    WHERE rn == 1;
```